# Best Practice for Mailbox Backup (IMAP)? With Webinterface?

Tags: linux, postfix, backup, imap

Situation: Debian Mailserver with ISPconfig3, Postfix and Dovecot, about 500 Users with different Domains.
Server is a virtual client, so i backup it via XenBackup.
Problem: If a user delete a single email, i don't want to restore the whole server for it.

Is there a solution to just backup mailboxes directly on the server?
Or is there a function like dumpster in Exchange?

I thought about a BCC option in the postfix config, but i think its not that practical.

It doesn't matter if it cost something, i would prefer a commercial product if it work good (maybe with Webinterface to restore).

Answer (score 1):

If you set up the servers like it was described in the ispconfig documentation then all the emails are in the folder /var/vmail/. You only have to backup this folder along with all subfolders.

A restore can be done by doing a copy of the old mailbox folder content in there again.

The structure is like this: /var/vmail/domain.com/before_at_sign

Comment: Thanks! Is there a backup/restore solution via web interface? I have to give it to customer who can't use shell.

Comment: I am not aware of any included in ispconfig. I am pretty sure there is none. You could write a simple web interface for http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Sync or maybe use the roundcube extention of ispconfig and maybe roundcube has then itself an extention which could provide you what you need. But I am not sure about this.

Comment: Another possibility is if you do the backup with http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/ and then give the user access to backuppc. But the user would need to be able to understand what he is doing.